# SQL output in multiple columns of unequal length

Tags: php, sql

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result41))
{
   echo "<tr><td align='center'>" .$row['AdmitRollNo'] . " </td></tr>";
}
```

This returns around 50 Admit Roll Numbers in a single column of the table. But I need the output in 5 columns containing respectively 9, 10, 7, 11, 13 items.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Using a [`modulus`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator in PHP would be a good start. This should work:

```
// Set how many items per column.
$per_column = 9;

// Set the opening table row.
echo "<tr>";

// Setting the counter to 0.
$counter = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result41)) {
   // Increment the counter by one.
   $counter++;

   // Do a modulus check between the counter & the per column value.
   if ($counter % $per_column == 0) {
     echo "</tr><tr>";
   }

   // Echo the table data columns.
   echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['AdmitRollNo'] . " </td>";

}

// Set the closing table row.
echo "</tr>";
```

But you say `9, 10, 7, 11, 13` items per each column. A bit trickier. But I believe that can be done. And here is a concept I just whipped up. The idea is there is an array of per column values named `$per_column_array` plus a counter named `$per_counter`.  The first time the modulus is reached, the counter is incremented by one, so the next `$per_column_array` value is grabbed.

```
// Set how many items per column.
$per_counter = 0;
$per_column_array = array(9, 10, 7, 11, 13);

// Set the opening table row.
echo "<tr>";

// Setting the counter to 0.
$counter = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result41)) {
   // Increment the counter by one.
   $counter++;

   // Do a modulus check between the counter & the per column value.
   if ($counter % $per_column_array[$per_counter] == 0) {
     $per_counter++;
     echo "</tr><tr>";
   }

   // Echo the table data columns.
   echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['AdmitRollNo'] . " </td>";

}

// Set the closing table row.
echo "</tr>";
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:** Here is an attempt with columns. Please feel free to adjust but the basic concept is the values are placed in a nested `<table>` within the `<table>` structure you already have:

```
// Set how many items per column.
$per_counter = 0;
$per_column_array = array(9, 10, 7, 11, 13);

// Set the opening table row.
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result41)) {
   // Increment the counter by one.
   $counter++;

   // Do a modulus check between the counter & the per column value.
   if ($counter % $per_column_array[$per_counter] == 0) {
     $per_counter++;
     echo "</table>";
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo "<table>";
   }

   // Echo the table data columns.
   echo "<tr><td align='center'>" . $row['AdmitRollNo'] . " </td></tr>";

}

// Set the closing table row.
echo "</table>";
echo "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But in this case data moves rowwise. But I need it columnwise i.e, after completion of the first column, the 2nd column can be used..